# How to shift the UItable View down and anchor it to an image programatically

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uikit

Hello what I have is a UITableViewController which displays various sliding out menu options. The idea I have is instead of the menu options to be displayed right below the navigation bar but rather include an image and have these items displayed below the image. I tried to anchor the UITable view to the bottom anchor of the image but it does not work.
Below are some images:
[image: Image from the view Hierarchy]

```
class MenuViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    public var delegate: MenuControllerDelagate?
    private let menuItems: [MenuOptions]
    let darkColour = UIColor(displayP3Red: 33/255.0, green: 33/255.0, blue: 33/255.0, alpha: 1)
    
    private let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "venom-7")
        return iv
    }()
    
    init(with menuItems: [MenuOptions]) {
        self.menuItems = menuItems
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(profileImageView)
        profileImageView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor)
        profileImageView.setDimensions(height: 130, width: 130)
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 130/2
        profileImageView.centerX(inView: view)
        tableView.backgroundColor = darkColour
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuItems.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
        cell.textLabel?.text = menuItems[indexPath.row].rawValue
        cell.backgroundColor = darkColour
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName: MenuOptions.allCases[indexPath.row].imageName)
        cell.imageView?.tintColor = .white
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true )
        let selectedItem = menuItems[indexPath.row]
        delegate?.didSelectMenuItem(named: selectedItem)
    }
}
```

Any advice how I could properly anchor the list items to be below the image would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using `UITableViewController` and it doesn't explicitly add `subviews` as `UIViewCroller`. Your must conform `ViewController`  to `UIViewController`.

After that initialize your `UITableView`

```
lazy var tableView: UITableView {
let tableView = UITableView()
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
return tableView
}
```

and in `viewDidLoad()` write

```
view.addSubview(tableView)
```

then create a function

```
func setupViews() {
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50),
            profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
            
        ])
}
```

and call the `setupViews()` in viewDidLoad

Comment: Yep you were right with this thought it worked. Definitely needed to imbed the UITableViewController into the UIViewController! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, instead of using UITableviewController you should use a UIViewController and add a UITableView in it then set the constraints.

```
class MenuViewController: UITableViewController
```

Instead use

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController {
   private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
...
}
}
```

Set the constraints now and subview. I think that would solve the issue